# After hours data - Interactive Brokers

Tags: programming, interactive-brokers

I just started using Interactive Brokers because of their API. I'm using the IBrokers package in R.
I've managed to get data for S&P 500 and other indices but now I want data for S&P 500 after hours.
[Investing.com](https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures) shows data for S&P 500 after hours (S&P 500 futures). How can I get this data by using  Interactive brokers API?

**Update**

I just tried this without success. I only get data for regular trading hours.

`spx = reqHistoricalData(tws2, twsIndex(symbol = "SPX", exch = "CBOE"),
                        barSize = "15 mins",
                        duration = "1 M",
                        useRTH = "0")`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I would also suggest you to ask this in the [TWS API] discussion group: https://groups.io/g/twsapi There is a vibrant community there of coders working with several aspects of the Interactive Brokers API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `reqHistoricalData` has an argument `useRTH` ("use regular trading hours"). Set `useRTH = "0"` to get data outside those hours.

This can only work for the futures, not for the index, which is only computed during normal trading hours.

```
library("IBrokers")
tws <- twsConnect()

contract <- twsContract(local = "ESH9",
                        sectype = "FUT",
                        exch = "GLOBEX",
                        currency = "USD",
                        include_expired = "1",
                        conId = "", symbol = "", primary = "", 
                        expiry = "", strike = "", right = "",
                        multiplier = "", combo_legs_desc = "",
                        comboleg = "", secIdType = "", secId = "")

reqHistoricalData(tws,
                  contract,
                  barSize = "15 mins",
                  duration = "1 M",
                  useRTH = "0")
```